# Verificar se a tarefa não foi executada e realizar - python

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer um sistema que envia mensagens pelo telegram , porém preciso que seja enviada a cada 3 horas então fiz o seguinte código

```
from time import localtime, strftime

horas = strftime("%H", localtime())

# Horários para enviar as mensagens

horario_to_send = '03', '06', '09', '13', '15', '18', '21', '23'

# Verifica se está no horário de mandar a mensagem , 

if horas in horario_to_send:
    #codigo
```

porém o mesmo está em um laço de repetição infinito , então sempre que ele passa pela condição para verificar a hora ele o executa , mas eu queria que ele executasse apenas uma vez a cada hora , o código fica o dia todo rodando, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui galera , não acredito que fui tão leigo , segue a solução.

```
from time import strftime, time

horas_minutos = strftime("%H:%M", localtime())

# Horários para enviar as mensagens

horario_to_send = '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '13:00', '14:00', '18:00', '21:00', '23:00'

# Verifica se está no horário de mandar a mensagem

if horas_minutos in horario_to_send:
    #code
```

adicionei os minutos , assim ele só executa em horas certas.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).